# Taylor Expansion Subseries

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

If we Taylor expand an infinitely differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ around a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we of course get:

$$ f(x) = f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + \cdots $$

We can extract a factor $(x-a)$:

$$ f(x) = f(a) + (x-a) \left(f'(a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a) + \frac{f^{(3)}(a)}{3!}(x-a)^2 + \cdots \right) $$

We will call the new series $h(x)$ such that:

$$ f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)h(x) $$

Now let us Taylor expand $f' : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ around $a \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$ f'(x) = f'(a) + \frac{f''(a)}{1!}(x-a) + \frac{f^{(3)}(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + \cdots$$

We see therefore $f'(x) \neq h(x)$.

I know enough to get to this point, but I don't know how to investigate further. Clearly, the two functions' Taylor expansions look similar. Additionally, $h(a) = f'(a)$.

Is there a closed form of the relationship between $h(x)$ and $f'(x)$? Alternatively, is there a common name for the subseries $h(x)$, given this interesting relationship?

Comment: Taking derivative on both sides of $f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)h(x)$ gives that $f'(x)=h(x)+(x-a)h'(x)$.

Comment: This led me another interesting property: $f(x) = f(a) + f'(x)(x-a) - h'(x)(x-a)^2$. So $h'(x)$ acts as a 2nd-order error-correction for the 1st-order (linear) approximation of $f$ by $f'$?

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$
f(x) = f(a) + (x - a)h(x)
$$

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(x) =& \frac{d}{dx}f(a) + \frac{d}{dx}(x - a)h(x) \\
=& 0 + \frac{d}{dx}xh(x) - \frac{d}{dx}ah(x) \\
=& h(x) + xh'(x) - ah'(x) \\
=& h(x) + (x - a)h'(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

So, the relationship you're looking for is
$$
f'(x) = h(x) + (x - a)h'(x)
$$

As a way to verify this, note that this implies $f'(a) = h(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

I want to notice a few connections between $h$ and $f'$, I hope it will be useful.

Let us rewrite your equation for $x \neq a$: $$f(x) = f(a) + (x - a) h(x) \Leftrightarrow \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = h(x)$$

This function $h(x)=h(x; a)$ is known as the [Difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient).
This will be continuous function: in all points $x \neq a$ denominator don't vanish and in $x=a$: $$\lim_{x \to a}h(x) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} \overset{def}{=} f'(a) $$ and as you noted $h(a)= f'(a)$.

Also, let's take the average of the derivative on the interval $[a, x]$:
$$\frac{1}{x-a}\int_{a}^x f'(t) dt = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = h(x; a)$$

This is why we call this $h$ as the 'average' value of a derivative.

Finally, from the mean value theorem $h(x) = f'(c)$ for some $c$ on interval $[a, x]$. We can interpret the mean value theorem as "at some point on the interval the instantaneous rate of change will be the same as the average rate of change".